# <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…". Error while creating a line chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a line chart using a csv file but get the same error: " attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…" here is the code:

```
**async function drawLineChart() {
  const dataset = await d3.csv("./../../data.csv");
  const dateParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  const xAccessor = d => dateParser(d.Orderdate);
  yAccessor = d => Number(d.Sales);
  ///Dimensions///
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  let dimensions = {
    width: width,
    height: width * 0.5,
    margin: {
      top: 10,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 50
    }
  };
  dimensions.boundedWidth =
    dimensions.width - dimensions.margin.left - dimensions.margin.right;
  dimensions.boundedHeight =
    dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.top - dimensions.margin.bottom;
  ///Canvas////
  const wrapper = d3
    .select("#wrapper")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", dimensions.width)
    .attr("height", dimensions.height);
  const bounds = wrapper
    .append("g")
    .style(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.margin.left}px, ${dimensions.margin.top}px)`
    );
  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor))
    .range([dimensions.boundedHeight, 0])
    .nice();
  const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
    .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth]);
  const lineGenerator = d3
    .line()
    .x(d => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
    .y(d => yScale(yAccessor(d)));
  const line = bounds
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", lineGenerator(dataset))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);
}
drawLineChart();**
```

I tried converting sales for yAccessor from string to number using "d => +d.Sales" and also "d => Number(d.Sales), but no luck, same error.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle and please add dummy dataset that you are using.

Comment: Print dataset (console.log(dataset) ) before you call lineGenerator with it.

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/nvd38gba/
thank you.

Comment: it prints the full dataset when I console.log(dataset)

Comment: `MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL...` looks like a proper svg path `M...,L...,...L...` but with `NaN` instead of numbers. Sounds like your data is bad, whether from the source, parsing, or manipulation.

Comment: ok that's correct, the issue was with parsing the date I was using ("%m-%d-%Y") instead of using ("%m/%d/%Y")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a dummy dataset and created a line chart. Seems like an issue with lineGenerator function. You were not using d.OrderDate and d.Sales inside x and y function of lineGenerator function.

```js
 const dataset = [{
     Orderdate: new Date(2010, 1, 1),
     Sales: 10
   },
   {
     Orderdate: new Date(2010, 2, 1),
     Sales: 20
   },
   {
     Orderdate: new Date(2010, 3, 1),
     Sales: 30
   },
   {
     Orderdate: new Date(2010, 4, 1),
     Sales: 40
   },
   {
     Orderdate: new Date(2010, 5, 1),
     Sales: 50
   },
 ];
 
  const dateParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

  const width = window.innerWidth;

 let dimensions = {
   width: width,
   height: 500,
   margin: {
     top: 10,
     right: 30,
     bottom: 50,
     left: 50
   }
 };
 dimensions.boundedWidth =
   dimensions.width - dimensions.margin.left - dimensions.margin.right;
 dimensions.boundedHeight =
   dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.top - dimensions.margin.bottom;
 ///Canvas////
 const wrapper = d3
   .select("#wrapper")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", dimensions.width)
   .attr("height", dimensions.height);

 const bounds = wrapper
   .append("g")
   .style(
     "transform",
     `translate(${dimensions.margin.left}px, ${dimensions.margin.top}px)`
   );

 var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .range([dimensions.boundedHeight, 0])
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
     return d.Sales;
   })]);

 // set the ranges
 var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
   .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])
   .domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
     return d.Orderdate;
   }));

 const lineGenerator = d3
   .line()
   .x(function(d) {
     return xScale(d.Orderdate);
   })
   .y(function(d) {
     return yScale(d.Sales);
   });
   
  const line = bounds
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", lineGenerator(dataset))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Tried to implement your method but still got the same error, thank you for doing that though.

Comment: Can you please try by just pasting my code. Because i have just worked on the code provided by you. If the issue still persist, can you please create a jsfiddle as mad by me, it would be easier to debug.

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/nvd38gba/
also to note that I was order date and sales inside x & y functions using xAccessor and yAccessor

Comment: we dont need to do this and one more thing you are not using the code published by me here.

Comment: Please check here, its working - https://jsfiddle.net/s893pn4e/